# How do I replace the supervisor ID for employees in a dataset with the highest level supervisor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataset like this

| emp_id | sup_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | N/A |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | N/A |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 7 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 11 | 19 |

Employees 1 and 7 are the highest level supervisors ('team leads') and can be identified with an 'N/A' sup_id value, and under them are a hierarchy of employees. I need to map each employee to their corresponding team lead supervisor ID. For example, employees 4-6 should be mapped to sup_id=1, not 2 or 3, given that 1 is the team lead. Correspondingly, employees 8,9 and 10 will be mapped to employee 7. Employee 11, however, is not mapped to any team lead and thus should remain untouched.

I tried creating a recursive function to iterate through every employee id but to no avail:

```py
def map_to_project_lead(employee_df, employee_id):
    # Check if the employee ID exists in the DataFrame
    if employee_id not in employee_df['employee_id'].values:
        return None

    # Get the supervisor ID for the given employee
    supervisor_id = employee_df.loc[employee_df['employee_id'] == employee_id, 'supervisor_id'].values[0]
    
    # If the supervisor is not a project lead (supervisor_id != 'NA'), recursively map to project lead
    if supervisor_id != 'NA':
        supervisor_id = map_to_project_lead(employee_df, supervisor_id)
    
    return supervisor_id

def map_supervisors_to_project_lead(df):
     result_df = df.copy()

    for index, row in result_df.iterrows():
        # Get the employee ID and supervisor ID
        employee_id = row['employee_id']
        supervisor_id = row['supervisor_id']

        # Map supervisor to project lead
        mapped_supervisor_id = map_to_project_lead(df, employee_id)

        # Update supervisor ID only if the employee is connected to a project lead
        if mapped_supervisor_id is not None:
            result_df.at[index, 'supervisor_id'] = mapped_supervisor_id

    return result_df
```

Comment: You should represent this data with a directed-graph. Build a directed-graph, with a node for each employee and the edges defined by the supervisor (parent) and employee (child) relationships. You can then locate the supervisors as all nodes with "in-degree" of zero (i.e. zero incoming edges). You could use the NetworkX package for this for instance, and build a `DiGraph` object, and then use `in_degree` to find the supervisors.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/):

```
import networkx as nx

# build the directed graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.dropna(subset=['sup_id']),
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                            source='sup_id', target='emp_id')

# find the roots (leaders)
roots = {n for n in G if G.in_degree(n)==0}
roots

# for each subgraph
# get the intersection with roots
# take the first item as leader
# build a dictionary
mapper = {n: next(iter(roots&g))
          for g in nx.weakly_connected_components(G)
          for n in g}

# map the leaders
df['team_leader'] = df['emp_id'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
    emp_id  sup_id  team_leader
0        1     NaN          1.0
1        2     1.0          1.0
2        3     1.0          1.0
3        4     2.0          1.0
4        5     2.0          1.0
5        6     3.0          1.0
6        7     NaN          7.0
7        8     7.0          7.0
8        9     7.0          7.0
9       10     9.0          7.0
10      11    19.0         19.0
```